# Smarty - making/converting a contact form

Tags: smarty, contact-form

I'm trying to implement a contact form into a website I'm making. Nobody recommends to just include the php file into a template.

I don't understand how to make or convert an existing contact form to one working with Smarty.

Any guidelines ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the purpose of smarty is to seperate your code logic from your design template.

So in your contact form, instead of using `echo`, you should write the output to smarty variables. I.e:

```
$smarty->assign('email', $email);
```

At the end of your contact forms PHP you should then load the smarty template

```
$smarty->display('index.tpl');
```

I would advice you to read the [smarty best practices page](http://www.smarty.net/best_practices) as well. It gives detailed information on how smarty templates should be used (and also why not to include plain PHP).